# How to create interactive online map with contour (filled) plot layer?

Tags: dictionary, openlayers, leaflet, heatmap, contour

I would like to create an online interactive map with filled contour plot layer like the ones can be seen on openweathermaps (I would like to use my own data for the plots).

What I need is also similar to the Leaflet heatmap (heatmap.js) but without dynamically changing the colors and the extent of the graphical objects (as in case of heatmap.js). Let's call them static heat maps.

I would like to know which mapping code/library can be used to produce such maps. 
I am really newbie to these things, so please bear with me.

I tried Leaflet but did not find any plugin which would create filled contour map layers (static heatmap). I created the following map with Leaflet where the rectangles are geojson polylines and the color is based on some assigned values to every rectangle (elevation)

[my leaflet attempt](https://2f25bf29b32f22877a00dc5140ac32d7935e15c2.googledrive.com/host/0B-HiMNYNuGpbdkNzR2Z1eEo1U28/snow_map_en.html)

The problem with this approach is that if higher resolution (smaller and more rectangles) is needed the site would really slow down.
I checked OpenLayers but did not see any similar examples.

I have the data in a matrix format:
Lat; Long; Value
.
.
Values are given in every gridpoints.

(if needed I would convert into other formats, like in case of the above attempt into geojson format)

The data is static, would be saved on the server.
So what I basically want to accomplish is a site where some spatial data is represented as filled contour map (static heatmap) and it is plotted over a map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution to the problem using open-source programs and free, online service:

**(1)** Processing the data in a GIS program. I used **[QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/)**. I interpolated my data which is in grid points to get a high resolution raster map.

**(2)** Save the post-processed raster map as a georeferenced *.tif image.

**(3)** Import the image into **[TileMill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/)**. Remove the basemap and keep only the image as the only layer (style it).

**(4)** Export the 'map' from TileMill as MBTiles. This will save numerous *.png files (**tiles**) corresponding to different zoom levels. These are the same type as google or openstreetmap use for their online maps.

**(5)** Create a free account at **[Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/)** and create a new map project. Upload the MBTiles created by TileMill (can be directly uploaded from it). Style it.

**(6)** Use the Map ID corresponding to your created project to embed the map into html sites, e.g. the javascript code:

```
// Provide your access token
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'Mapbox will generate this for you';
// Create a map in the div #map
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'username.mapid', {
        minZoom: 5,
        maxZoom: 10
    }).setView([47, 20], 8);
```

**[Example hosted on Mapbox](https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/rozsasarpi.k60dg6ee/page.html?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoicm96c2FzYXJwaSIsImEiOiJFNVBFUU1ZIn0.d3mNPPGC5YgBVtPQFRTtYw#8/46.962/19.704)**

Sample image(I do not how long will the above link live):
[image]

In retrospect, the question would have been better fit to [GIS stack exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/).